# loading a template in php

Tags: php, content-management-system, themes

I'm building a small CMS in php but I have a problem with the front end. I have a folder name template inside the folder I got different themes

```
-admin
-template
 ---theme1
 ---theme2
 ---theme3
-index.php
```

when I load the index.php I can load the theme, but in the browser URL I get localhost/cms/template/theme1/page.php

but I like to have localhost/cms/page.php instead.

will you please tell me when I'm doing wrong!

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell anything without your code. Probably you should use PHP sessions and simple include theme files in index.php But without clarifying what you exactly want to achieve we can only guess

Comment: Hello Marcin,  all what I need is like wordpress. I just need to call the theme. this is my index.php file require_once('template/theme1.php');

Comment: I don't see any problem. If you have example.com/index.php and in browser you have http://example.com index.php simple include this theme1.php and it doesn't affect url

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused...you say this is a front end issue, but you point to the URL as the issue.

My guess is this: You need to identify different themes using separate **stylesheets in CSS**. Having different pages called page.php that looks differently definitely requires more work and complicates the issue. CSS was designed for you to customize the look of different pages and/or templates. Why not create 3 different stylesheets and then create a simple form that allows the administrator to choose which stylesheet to use (by **radio button**, or something else).

You can determine which stylesheet is "in use" in a number of ways - either on the back end or the front end. Given that this is a CMS, you'll probably want your administrators to choose the stylesheet and allow their selection to update a database entry or change a file on the back-end. No matter what you choose, you're URL's probably should not be affected.

Finally, you can rewrite URLs with **.htaccess**, but that can lead to more issues as you develop the site. Generally speaking - htaccess is overkill for issues like this.